# Discord Audio Player is silent when status is "Playing"

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, discord.js, bots

Pretty self-explanatory, really. I'm trying to re-code my Discord audio bot since Discord went and changed their bot API, and despite my best efforts the bot still produces no sound.

Here's the relevant bits of code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"],
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"]
});
let connection;
let player;

async function playMusic() {
    player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
        guildId: message.guild.id, 
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    }).subscribe(player);
    
    /* some code that sets songFile */
    
    let resource = createAudioResource(createReadStream(songFile));
    player.play(resource);
}
```

Calling this causes the bot to join the voice call, but it plays no sound. It says that the current state is `AudioPlayerStatus.Playing`, though, so I don't know what's happening there.

I've verified that the filepath for songFile is correct and the resource is successfully created. All the code is nested in `try/catch` blocks, so I know no errors are being raised. I've also included the `intents` in case I'm missing one there, but from other questions I've seen on this website `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` seems to be the key one.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please visit [@discordjs/voice](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/main/packages/voice) repository, and check `Installation` section in README.md. In order to play audio, you have to install several packages, one from each group:

**Encryption Libraries (npm install):**

`sodium-native: ^3.3.0`
`sodium: ^3.0.2`
`tweetnacl: ^1.0.3`
`libsodium-wrappers: ^0.7.9`

**Opus Libraries (npm install):**
`@discordjs/opus: ^0.4.0`
`opusscript: ^0.0.7`

**FFmpeg:**

`FFmpeg (installed and added to environment)`
`ffmpeg-static: ^4.2.7 (npm install)`

Hope it helps someone :)